# Send in a number and return an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need some help with the following:

1. in a method create a new array based on the input parameter
2. return an array from that method
3. output the contents of the array the most elegantly?

mycontroller.rb

```
def test(num)
  #take the number and create a new array and return the array with the numbers.
  #example input: 5
  #output: array with 5 indexes and values of [1,2,3,4,5]
end

# output the contents of the array
i = 0
while i < 5
  puts test(i)
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: If that is not a question, then you need to go back to elementary school to find out what the definition of "question" is.  And this is not homework.  I am learning Ruby and need help understanding it.

Comment: Then ask a question. You have a list of three unrelated requirements which does not constitute a question, and Stack Overflow is absolutely *not* about writing your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ruby ranges](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html) for this:

```
list = (1..num).to_a
```

To print an array use the `inspect` method, i.e.

```
puts list.inspect
```

Comment: +1 for a trivial solution to a trivial task.

Comment: `puts foo.inspect` is the same as `p foo` isn't it?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, it is the same. If the user wants the pretty string for further modification, `foo.inspect` is handy. Eg: `puts "The list is content is #{foo.inspect}"`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
def test(num)
  1.upto(num).to_a
end
```

And for the output:

```
puts test(5).join(', ') # outputs "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to go about this definition.

I always prefer to tell beginners to write code that they can read like a book, using the most easy to understand methods and classes of the language, in this case I would recommend:

```
def num_array(num)
    array = Array.new
    count = 1
    num.times {
      array << count
      count =  count + 1
    }
    return array
end
```

and to check it with:

```
i = 1
while i <= 5
  new_array = Array.new
  new_array = num_array(i)
  puts new_array.inspect
  i = i + 1
end
```

Yes the code example that I supplied could be simplified a lot, but any beginner that has at least read a tutorial on Ruby should be able to understand and replicate the above code, once they are comfortable with the language they can start making changes to more complex syntax.

Like swapping `i = i + 1` to `i += 1`.

or swapping all of the above to `list = (1..num).to_a`.